# PrimeFaces dialog close on click outside of the dialog

Tags: primefaces

I have a typical primefaces dialog and it works great but I can't find any options to have it close when someone clicks outside the dialog. I have seen a few jquery examples and I'm guessing I can adapt those for the primefaces dialog but first wanted to make sure there wasn't a solution already?

Thanks.

Comment: Someone posted a way to do it with onclick on the body of the page, that will probably work. I replaced the dialog with an overlaypanel which does this by default and served other purposes for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a javascript function for onClick event and close the dialog.

```
<h:body onclick="closeDialog();">

function closeDialog(){
   widgetWarDialog.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just sharing my solution that works globally for any modal dialog. Code adapted from http://blog.hatemalimam.com/get-widgetvar-by-id/ .

When you show a dialog, a mask (that has the .ui-dialog-mask class) is created, and it has the id of the opened dialog, appended with a "_modal" keyword.

This scripts gets that id when that mask is clicked, removes that appended text, and finds the corresponding widget to be closed.

To use it, just save the code on a .js file, import on your page and it will work.

Tested on Primefaces 6.0.

```
    /**
     * Listener to trigger modal close, when clicked on dialog mask.
     */
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click",'.ui-dialog-mask',function () {
        idModal = this.id;
        idModal = idModal.replace("_modal","");
        getWidgetVarById(idModal).hide();
    })
});

    /**
     * Returns the PrimefacesWidget from ID
     * @param id
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function getWidgetVarById(id) {
        for (var propertyName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
            var widget = PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName];
            if (widget && widget.id === id) {
                return widget;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. This beats changing a lot of p:dialogs into p:overlayPanel.

Comment: This works in desktop mode but not on mobile (iPhone Safari). Got any tips on how to make this work on mobile?

Comment: To make this work on mobile, add -- touch or touchstart or tap, etc. But this worked for me: `$("body").on("click touchstart",'.ui-dialog-mask',function ()`

Comment: Good thing also is, that this solution is not global. Just include the JS on the page you need dismissable dialogs for and no other code is affected.

Answer (score 0):

I have an other solution for a "modal" primefaces dialog.

I just want to add the click event, when my button is clicked to open the Dialog. And not allways when i click anything on the body element.

Add a styleClass to your button. For example styleClass="mybutton-class".
Then add a widgetVar to your `<p:dialog widgetVar="widgetVarName" ...>`

```
        jQuery(".mybutton-class").on("click", function() {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function(){
                PF('widgetVarName').hide();
            })
        });
```

Additional for Ajax Update Events:

I build 3 JS functions.

```
//for the first time the page is loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    onLoadFunction();
});

//to load the script after you reload your page with ajax
jQuery(document).on("pfAjaxComplete", function(){
    onLoadFunction();
});

//your code you handle with
function onLoadFunction(){
   jQuery(".mybutton-class").on("click", function() {
       jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function(){
           PF('widgetVarName').hide();
       })
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an 8 years old question, but recently I meet the same problem and here is my solution for a modal primefaces dialog.

I wrote a js function which adds a listener to overlay panel around the dialogue

```
function addListenerOnDialogueOverlay() {
    document.getElementById('test-dialog_modal')
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            PF('test-dialog-widget').hide();
        });
}
```

and call the finction in "onShow" tag of the dialogue

```
<p:dialog id="test-dialog"
          widgetVar="test-dialog-widget"          
          modal="true"          
          onShow="addListenerOnDialogueOverlay()">
```